# how to create an arrayList(?) of arrayList of arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist `outer` which consists of multiple `List<String> inner` . I want to create an arraylist (or any other kind of list/set for that matter) of different values of `outer` , and I'm stuck on how to do it. Following is how I want the list to be structured:

```
wantThisList -> 
 {  [ [innerListofStrings1], [innerListOfStrings2] ] ,
    [ [innerListOfStrings3], [innerListOfStrings4] ] ,
    ....                                                }
```

This is how I've instantiated my lists:

```
List<List<String>> outer = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
     List<String> inner1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> inner2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and sample lists, something similar to what I'm doing: (please read the comment)

```
for(String elements : SomeList){
             outer.clear();
             inner1.clear();
             inner2.clear();

             inner1.add("abc");
             inner1.add("xyz");
             inner2.add("ijk");
             inner2.add("mno");

             outer.add(inner1);
             outer.add(inner2);
            // NewListofAllOuters.add(outer);  //can I do something like this? If yes, what should be this list type? 
}

NewListofAllOuters = ??? //how to add each of this outer(with 2 inner list entities) as one row in NewListofAllOuters????
```

**EDIT:**
Output I want when printing this `NewListOfAllOuters` on console:

```
[   [[abc,xyz],[ijk, mno]], [[abc,xyz],[ijk, mno]] , [[abc,xyz],[ijk, mno]] ,... ]
```

Can anyone help me in using the correct Collection to define this `NewListofAllouters`?

Comment: You can, but you `clear` your `List`(s). And thus it would always be empty.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to add a new element with each iteration of `SomeList` , so that each new row in `NewListOfAllOuters`  has just one new `Outer`

Comment: Then you will need new `Outer` ***instances***. Trying to reuse the `List`(s) is why you are getting empty `List`(s). Oh, and you can't add two `String`(s) to a `List` with a single `add`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks! I didn't realise adding two strings, just was creating some sample code to get the idea out there. I'll correct that. Also, by instances, I'm assuming you mean class instances (sorry for the novice statement) but I was looking for a way to not create an Outer class for this apparently small thing. Is creating an `Outer` class the only way?

Comment: No. Sorry. Outer `List` instances. When you call `inner1.clear();` you clear the `List` stored in `outer`, and when you call `outer.clear()` you would clear the list of lists stored in `NewListofAllOuters`. All Java object types (including `List`s) are **reference types**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Okay, so assuming I fix that and just clear the `inner` lists; Now my outer would still have empty lists that I Can get rid of using something like `list.removeIf(List::isEmpty)` . After all that is done, how should I be creating this `NewListOfAllOuters` instance?

Comment: You shouldn't. Why do you think you need to copy `outer` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be very confused about `List`(s) and copies generally, the elements are not copied when you add or create a `List`; so clearing the `List` instances is not going to work. Assuming I understand your goal, you only need `outer` and a loop to populate it. Like,

```
List<List<String>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    outer.add(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));
    outer.add(Arrays.asList("ijk", "mno"));
}
System.out.println(outer);
```

Which outputs

```
[[abc, xyz], [ijk, mno], [abc, xyz], [ijk, mno], [abc, xyz], [ijk, mno], [abc, xyz], [ijk, mno]]
```

Because `outer` is a `List` of `List`(s). If you ***really*** want it to a depth of three, you still only need a single `outer` List. Like,

```
List<List<List<String>>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    List<List<String>> inner = new ArrayList<>();
    outer.add(inner); // <-- note that this inner reference is used on the next two lines.
    inner.add(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));
    inner.add(Arrays.asList("ijk", "mno"));
}
System.out.println(outer);
```

Which outputs (as you said you wanted)

```
[[[abc, xyz], [ijk, mno]], [[abc, xyz], [ijk, mno]], [[abc, xyz], [ijk, mno]], [[abc, xyz], [ijk, mno]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eliot. It cleared a lot of confusion in my mind! I indeed **really** needed the Lists to a depth of three, and this was helpful :)